# How do I inherit shared code in a Scala unapply function?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, unapply

I have Scala code with some boilerplate, and I figure it's Scala, so I must be doing something wrong. I need some help figuring out how to remove the redundancies.

```
trait Number {
  val x: Int
}

case class EvenNumber(x: Int) extends Number

object EvenNumber {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[EvenNumber] = {
    val x = s.toInt
    if (x % 2 == 0) Some(EvenNumber(x))
    else None
  }
}

case class OddNumber(x: Int) extends Number

object OddNumber {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[OddNumber] = {
    val x = s.toInt
    if (x % 2 == 1) Some(OddNumber(x))
    else None
  }
}
```

In this simple example there are even numbers and odd numbers which are subtypes of a general number type. Both even and odd numbers have extractors that allow them to be created from strings. This enables use cases like the following.

```
scala> "4" match {case EvenNumber(n) => n;case _ => None}
// returns EvenNumber(4)

scala> "5" match {case EvenNumber(n) => n;case _ => None}
// returns None

scala> "4" match {case OddNumber(n) => n;case _ => None}
// returns None

scala> "5" match {case OddNumber(n) => n;case _ => None}
// returns OddNumber(5)
```

The source code for the two extractors is identical except for the result of the `x % 2` operation (`0` or `1`) and the extracted type (`EvenNumber` or `OddNumber`). I'd like to be able to write the source once and parameterize on these two values, but I can't figure out how. I've tried various type parameterizations to no avail.

The Stackoverflow question "[How to use extractor in polymorphic unapply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098066/how-to-use-extractor-in-polymorphic-unapply)" is related but different, because my implementing classes are not distinguished by the types they contain by rather by the string inputs they recognize.

---

Here is a revised version of the code incorporating comments I received in addition to the original post. (As is often the case, the first round of answers helped me figure out what my *real* question was.)

```
import scala.util.Try

trait Number {
  val x: Int
}

object NumberParser {
  def parse[N <: Number](s: String, remainder: Int, n: Int => N): Option[N] =
    Try {s.toInt}.toOption.filter(_ % 2 == remainder).map(n(_))
}

case class EvenNumber(x: Int) extends Number

object EvenNumber {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[EvenNumber] = NumberParser.parse(s, 0, EvenNumber(_))
}

case class OddNumber(x: Int) extends Number

object OddNumber {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[OddNumber] = NumberParser.parse(s, 1, OddNumber(_))
}
```

Factoring out a static `NumberParser.parse` function is a reasonable solution. I would still like to have have syntactic sugar that obviated my repeating `unapply` lines in all of my case classes, since in a more complicated example that had more than two that could get ugly. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

More crucially, the use case I really want to support is the following.

```
 scala> "5" match {case EvenNumber(n) =>n;case OddNumber(n) => n;case _ => None}
 // returns OddNumber(5)

 scala> "4" match {case EvenNumber(n) =>n;case OddNumber(n) => n;case _ => None}
 // returns EvenNumber(4)

 scala> "x" match {case EvenNumber(n) =>n;case OddNumber(n) => n;case _ => None}
 // returns None
```

Again this is fine for two cases, but in a different application where there are more than two it can become unmanageable. I want to write a single case

```
s match {case Number(n) => n; case _ => None}
```

which returns `OddNumber(5)`, `EvenNumber(4)`, `None` as above.
I can't figure out how to write my `Number` supertype to support this. Is it possible in Scala?

---

*Edit*: Wrote a description of my final answer with additional commentary in "[Runtime Polymorphism with Scala Extractors](http://cornercases.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/runtime-polymorphism-with-scala-extractors/)".

Comment: See my updated answer to `Number` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why inherit?

```
object Mod2Number {
  def parse[A <: Number](s: String, i: Int, n: Int => A) = {
    val x = s.toInt
    if (x % 2 == i) Some(n(x))
    else None
  }
}

case class EvenNumber(x: Int) extends Number
object EvenNumber {
  def unapply(s: String) = Mod2Number.parse(s, 0, n => EvenNumber(n))
}
```

But if even that is too much noise you can go one step further:

```
trait Makes[A <: Number] { 
  def apply(i: Int): A
  def mod: Int
  def unapply(s: String): Option[A] = {
    val x = s.toInt
    if (x % 2 == mod) Some(apply(x))
    else None
  }
}

case class EvenNumber(x: Int) extends Number
object EvenNumber extends Makes[EvenNumber] { def mod = 0 }
```

Comment: That works and is roughly the solution I came up with in my original application that led to this post. In that original application, however, there are just two concrete classes but a long list of them so even the bit of repeated code for your `unapply` function gets to be ugly.

Comment: @W.P.McNeill - I've edited in a solution with even less ugliness.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should catch exceptions on `toInt` - exceptions in pattern matching is something strange.

```
object EvenNumber {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = Try{s.toInt}.toOption.filter{_ % 2 == 0}
}

object OddNumber {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = Try{s.toInt}.toOption.filter{_ % 2 == 1}
}
```

You could extract similar code, but I don't think it's useful here:

```
class IntFilter(f: Int => Boolean) {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Int] = Try{s.toInt}.toOption.filter(f)
}

object EvenNumber extend IntFilter(_ % 2 == 0)

object OddNumber extend IntFilter(_ % 2 == 1)
```

**For edited question:**

```
s match {case Number(n) => n; case _ => None}
```

You could create object `Number` like this:

```
object Number{
  def unapply(s: String): Option[Number] = Try{s.toInt}.toOption.collect{
    case i if i % 2 == 0 => EvenNumber(i)
    case i if i % 2 == 1 => OddNumber(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that `filter` on `Try` gives a _huge_ performance penalty since you have to create an entire stack trace just to reject your value!  Way better to filter after you `toOption` it.